# Change permissions for others ONLY

Tags: linux, file-permissions, chmod

I have the following directories on the HDFS(which loosely follows the POSIX model) :

```
[ojoqcu@sandbox ~]$ hdfs dfs -ls /
Found 11 items
drwxrwxrwx   - yarn   hadoop          0 2016-03-14 14:19 /app-logs
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs   hdfs            0 2016-06-27 09:40 /apps
drwxr-xr-x   - yarn   hadoop          0 2016-03-14 14:19 /ats
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs   hdfs            0 2016-03-14 14:50 /demo
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs   hdfs            0 2016-03-14 14:19 /hdp
drwxr-xr-x   - mapred hdfs            0 2016-03-14 14:19 /mapred
drwxrwxrwx   - mapred hadoop          0 2016-03-14 14:19 /mr-history
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs   hdfs            0 2016-03-14 14:42 /ranger
drwxrwxrwx   - spark  hadoop          0 2016-06-27 10:02 /spark-history
drwxrwxrwx   - hdfs   hdfs            0 2016-06-27 09:38 /tmp
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs   hdfs            0 2016-06-27 09:38 /user
```

As obvious, the 'others' can freely operate on these directories.

I wish to keep the owner and group permissions unchanged/as-is but change the 'others' to custom form e.g

```
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs   hdfs            0 2016-06-27 09:40 /apps

to

drwxr-x---   - hdfs   hdfs            0 2016-06-27 09:40 /apps

drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs   hdfs            0 2016-03-14 14:19 /hdp

to

drwxr-xr--   - hdfs   hdfs            0 2016-03-14 14:19 /hdp
```

In extreme case, I may need to provide only read or no access at all to the other users e.g :

```
drwxrwxr--   - yarn   hadoop          0 2016-03-14 14:19 /app-logs
drwxr-xr--   - hdfs   hdfs            0 2016-06-27 09:40 /apps
drwxr-xr--   - yarn   hadoop          0 2016-03-14 14:19 /ats
drwxr-xr--   - hdfs   hdfs            0 2016-03-14 14:50 /demo
drwxr-xr--   - hdfs   hdfs            0 2016-03-14 14:19 /hdp
drwxr-xr--   - mapred hdfs            0 2016-03-14 14:19 /mapred
drwxrwxr--   - mapred hadoop          0 2016-03-14 14:19 /mr-history
drwxr-xr--   - hdfs   hdfs            0 2016-03-14 14:42 /ranger
drwxrwxr--   - spark  hadoop          0 2016-06-27 10:02 /spark-history
drwxrwxr--   - hdfs   hdfs            0 2016-06-27 09:38 /tmp
drwxr-xr--   - hdfs   hdfs            0 2016-06-27 09:38 /user
```

How can I recursively do this without specifying the bits for owner and group ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from here: https://www.washington.edu/computing/unix/permissions.html

> To change the mode of a file, use the chmod command. The general form is
>
> ```
>   chmod X@Y file1 file2 ...
> ```
>
> where: X is any combination of the letters 'u' (for owner), 'g' (for
>   group), 'o' (for others), 'a' (for all; that is, for `ugo'); @ is
>   either '+' to add permissions, '-' to remove permissions, or '=' to
>   assign permissions absolutely; and Y is any combination of 'r', 'w',
>   'x'. Following are some examples:
>
> ```
>  chmod u=rx file        (Give the owner rx permissions, not w)
>  chmod go-rwx file      (Deny rwx permission for group, others)
>  chmod g+w file         (Give write permission to the group)
>  chmod a+x file1 file2  (Give execute permission to everybody)
>  chmod g+rx,o+x file    (OK to combine like this with a comma)
> ```

so according this, answer will be:

```
chmod -R o-wx path
```

Comment: @fedorqui thanks for editing

Comment: No problem : ) I felt it was necessary to improve the readability